# Why the output size of imageView is different with .xml

Tags: java, android, xml, drag-and-drop, imageview

MainActivity.java

```
private ViewGroup rootLayout;
private int _xDelta;
private int _yDelta;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.view_root);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
    img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    img.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
}



private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
        }
        rootLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/view_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/cable"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The output expected

[activity_main.xml design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXoXs.png)

The result

[tested on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcd4L.png)

Please help me to change the size of imageView. Or show the coding part that can be altered. Please noted, i have tried to change the layout_width and layout_height but nothing changed.

Comment: why you are programically setting LayoutParams to imageView?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/view_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/cable" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

replace this code with yours

Comment: what is your image size and dimensions?

Comment: did you mean by this information? 348x250 PNG (32-bit color) 36.52K @Mohit Trivedi

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the resolution of the image file in your `drawable` folder is too small, therefore when it `wraps_content`, it is a small image. Try resizing the image or use hdpi, mdpi, xdpi, xxdpi and xxxdpi folders in you `drawable`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
Using this code

```
img.getLayoutParams().height = 1000;
img.getLayoutParams().width = 1000;
```

Thanks guys.